# How can I handle error Exception with try/catch using xslt 3.0

Tags: xslt-3.0

How can I handle error Exception with try/catch using xslt 3.0. I am finding in xml number Element. If number Element not find in parent product then generate a file error.txt and how to write the Exception.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <product dept="WMN">
        <name language="en">Fleece Pullover</name>
        <colorChoices>navy black</colorChoices>
    </product>
    <product dept="ACC">
        <number>563</number>
        <name language="en">Floppy Sun Hat</name>
    </product>
    <product dept="ACC">
        <number>443</number>
        <name language="en">Deluxe Travel Bag</name>
    </product>
    <product dept="MEN">
        <number>784</number>
        <name language="en">Cotton Dress Shirt</name>
        <colorChoices>white gray</colorChoices>
        <desc>Our <i>favorite</i> shirt!</desc>
    </product>
</catalog>
```

**Using XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:stream href="books.xml">
            <xsl:iterate select="catalog">
                <xsl:result-document href="out.xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:for-each select="product">
                            <xsl:try>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="number"/>
                                <xsl:catch>
                                    <xsl:result-document href="error.txt">
                                        <xsl:message>Element number not given in <xsl:value-of select="product/@dept"/></xsl:message>
                                    <error code="{$err:code}" message="{$err:description}"/>
                                    </xsl:result-document>
                                </xsl:catch>
                            </xsl:try>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:result-document>
            </xsl:iterate>
        </xsl:stream>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My requirement is how can I uses try/catch when not find the number element then make a file with error.

Comment: Do you need to use `xsl:try/xsl:catch`? A non-existing element will not cause a run-time error but you can of course simply check `xsl:if test="not(number)"` and then use `xsl:result-document` to output a document. Or you would need to raise the error yourself using the `error` function. It is also not clear whether you want to write a plain text error document or an `xsl:message` or both.

Comment: Hi Martin Sir, Just I want to know that how to work try/catch and throw the exception. Thanks for the reply Sir!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to generate error message in log file by taking the value in variable in then check some conditon:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:stream href="books.xml">
            <xsl:iterate select="catalog">
                <xsl:result-document href="out.xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:for-each select="product">
                            <xsl:variable name="num" select="if (number) then (number) else ('aaaa')"/>
                            <xsl:try>
                                <number>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($num, '############')"/>
                                </number>
                                <xsl:catch>
                                    <xsl:result-document href="error.log" omit-xml-declaration="yes">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x00a0;Element number not given in ', @dept)"/>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x00a0;Error code: ', $err:code, ' and Error Desc is: ', $err:description)"/>
                                    </xsl:result-document>
                                </xsl:catch>
                            </xsl:try>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:result-document>
            </xsl:iterate>
        </xsl:stream>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```